# When reopening file lose all information in radare2

Tags: radare2, debuggers

I have problem with my radare2, when I try to reopen file in debug mode (ood) my radare loses all informations about that file.

[image]

any help to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a radare2 problem. What you are experiencing is "Address space layout randomization" or ASLR. Basically every time that you run the program the addresses are different. all the breakpoints and info still in radare2 but they are not pointing to the same addresses since it change.

Radare2 has an option to disable ASLR while you used with radare2 (not normal running)

Inside of radare2 type:

```
> dor aslr=no
```

then analyze everything and start your job

```
> aaa
```

Happy hacking!